# CMake, GLFW3 OSX linking error

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glfw, clion

I've struggled for a while now linking GLFW libraries in my simple C++ project in CLion. I've gone through the existing problems and their solutions but they do not seem to help in my case. My CMakeLists file is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(TestGame)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -v")

find_library(carbon_lib Carbon)
find_library(cocoa_lib Cocoa)
find_library(iokit_lib IOKit)
find_library(corevideo_lib CoreVideo)
find_library(opengl_lib OpenGL)
find_library(corefoundation_lib CoreFoundation)

set(frameworks
    ${carbon_lib}
    ${cocoa_lib}
    ${iokit_lib}
    ${corevideo_lib}
    ${opengl_lib}
    ${corefoundation_lib}
    )

file(GLOB sources
    "include/*.hpp"
    "src/*.cpp"
    "src/application/*.cpp"
    "src/controlling/*.cpp"
    "src/helper/*.cpp"
    "src/render/*.cpp"
    "src/texturing/*.cpp"
    "src/translations/*.cpp"
    "test/*.cpp"
    )

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(GLFW3 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(GLM REQUIRED)
find_package(SOIL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR}     ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SOIL_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(GameMain ${sources})
target_link_libraries(GameMain ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${GLM_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${SOIL_LIBRARIES} ${frameworks})
```

I've got GLFW3 and GLFW2 (apparently v2 was required by Cocoa and I have no idea why) installed using brew (brew install glfw2 or brew install glfw3 - with --build-bottle --static it does not work because of internal cmake error), also tried the same with manually compiled GLFW from the latest sources.

It is to be noticed that I've recently started learning things about C++/CMake/CLion so I might forget about something important in here - do not hesitate to ask for more informations so I can add these.

It is also worth noticing that before Sierra OSX (currently running latest BETA) update my application just ran quite fine without linker errors. Linker errors are as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      Application::Application(char const*, int, int) in     Application.cpp.o
  "_glfwMakeContextCurrent", referenced from:
      Application::Application(char const*, int, int) in     Application.cpp.o
  "_glfwWindowHint", referenced from:
      Application::Application(char const*, int, int) in Application.cpp.o
  "_glfwWindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      Application::run() in Application.cpp.o
```

and these relates to main entry files where a window is created. CLion does not make any suggestion about anything being omitted while including directories. I tried with/without all these frameworks listed about, found a solution where Cocoa/IOKit/CoreVideo/OpenGL are to be included in order to make GLFW3 working. Tries also including Carbon/CoreFoundation because some solutions were about these.

Literally nothing works.

Comment: what is the output of make VERBOSE=1 ?

Comment: as a random aside, make sure you download the os x graphics tools: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=graphics   they're pretty helpful for debugging opengl issues.

Comment: Check which variables sets your `FindGLFW3.cmake` script. E.g. [this one](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindGLFW3.cmake) sets variables prefixed with `GLFW3_`. (But you use ones prefixed with `GLFW_`).

Comment: I've tried multiple modules for CMake for GLFW3 includes. I've changed mine to the one proposed in here and now the problem is as follows:

    `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_IODisplayCreateInfoDictionary", referenced from:
          _getDisplayName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      "_IOHIDDeviceCopyMatchingElements", referenced from:
          _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)`

and few more lines while the undefined symbols mentioned in the topic do not show again (they are linked properly I guess).

Comment: any luck solving the issue? @ŁukaszModliński

Answer (score 1):

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package

You need to add:

```
target_link_libraries(LearnGLSL ..any other libraries... glfw)
```

Comment: I've tried different combinations and also followed this guide too with no success at all.

Comment: The first thing to do is to come up with a hand crafted command that works.   You can start by running make VERBOSE=1 to get cmake to print out what it's actually doing, then copy paste that and start adjusting things til you get it to work by hand.